# How to use Kerberos for samba authentication

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, ntlm, samba

I have WS 2016 running as AD/DC on which NTLM/NTLMv2 is disabled (Kerberos is a way to go). I have successfully joined Ubuntu machine to it, using this tutorial "[Integrate Ubuntu with AD](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Horizon-7/7.13/linux-desktops-setup/GUID-F8F0CFCF-C4D6-4784-85FF-E7C6DF575F49.html)". Everything if working correctly (except Samba), can view users and groups on AD and can login to Ubuntu machine using AD user.

Now when I try to login with AD user to samba share I get NT_STATUS_NTLM_BLOCKED, which is expected, sense NTLM is blocked by AD.

Now my question is how to setup (force) Samba to use kerberos instead NTLM ?

Comment: Are you connecting _from_ an AD-joined machine while being logged in to AD user account? Are you getting a credential prompt while trying to connect (and if so, what username are you entering)?

Comment: I'm connecting to Samba server from android device, which (as far as I know) I can't join to domain. I've tried to login with domain (DOMAIN\username) and without (username) and in both cases I get same error as above.
While browsing through the internet, I noticed that some special configuration (CIFS and SPN for samba share server) needs to be properly setup in order for this to work. On most online pages I've seen that CIFS SPN needs to be generated within keytab for server that runs Samba, but when I joined my Samba machine that keytab file was automatically generated for that user.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're thinking that the SMB server just receives your password and then uses either NTLM or Kerberos to validate it. That's not how it works.

In SMB, it's *the client* which speaks NTLM or Kerberos when connecting to the server. You cannot force the server to use Kerberos because that is not the server's decision; it can either *offer* Kerberos or not, but it cannot make the client support Kerberos if the client doesn't support it.

Most mobile SMB client libraries do not have any Kerberos support (due to complexity); they will only use NTLM.

Comment: It seems that would be the issue. I went with assumption that android SMB clients support kerberos.

Answer (score 0):

My "solution" to this issue was simply to exclude specific server from NTLM restriction policy.

There are two policies, on active directory server, in "Local Group Policy/Computer Configuration/Windows Settings/Security Settings/Local Policies/Security options":

- Network security: Restrict NTLM: Add server exceptions in this domain
- Network security: Restrict NTLM: Add remote server exceptions for NTLM authentication

So servers that are defined under those two policies are able to use NTLM.

Not a solution, but for now it's a workaround.